# external integer is not correctly passed in to a lambda express in std::thread

Tags: c++, lambda, stdthread

Note: the following question is not asking how to pass an external variable to a lambda expression. The question is why the value passed into the lambda expression via capture clause is different from the original value of external variable when there are multiple threads. If there's one one thread, the code runs correctly. Also it pass by value instead of reference, it also works, i.e.

auto split_loop = [=](int idx)

===================================

I have a lambda expression passing all external integer variables via reference within a loop. The integer variables somehow can not be correctly passed

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

const int NUM_THREADS = 8;

std::mutex mu;

int main()
{
    std::thread td[NUM_THREADS];
    int tot = 100000;

    unsigned int idx_start = 0;
    unsigned int idx_end = 0;
    unsigned int gap = 1000;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i< NUM_THREADS; i++) {

        idx_start = i*gap;
        idx_end = idx_start+gap;

        //cout<<"1_  i: "<<i<<" idx_start: "<<idx_start<<" idx_end: "<<idx_end<<endl;
        //
        auto split_loop = [&](int idx)
        {

            mu.lock();
            cout<<"2_  i:"<<idx<<" idx_start: "<<idx_start<<" idx_end: "<<idx_end<<endl;
            mu.unlock();
        };


        td[i] = std::thread(split_loop, i);
    }
    //
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i< NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        td[i].join();
    }

}
```

I expected the two integer inside and outside the lambda expression to be synchronized, but they are not. For example, in the first loop, outside the lambda, idx_start: 0 idx_end: 1000, but inside the lambda,i:0 idx_start: 4000 idx_end: 5000.

the output outside the lambda is:

1_  i: 0 idx_start: 0 idx_end: 1000

1_  i: 1 idx_start: 1000 idx_end: 2000

1_  i: 2 idx_start: 2000 idx_end: 3000

1_  i: 3 idx_start: 3000 idx_end: 4000

1_  i: 4 idx_start: 4000 idx_end: 5000

1_  i: 5 idx_start: 5000 idx_end: 6000

1_  i: 6 idx_start: 6000 idx_end: 7000

1_  i: 7 idx_start: 7000 idx_end: 8000

---

the output inside the lambda is:

2_  i:0 idx_start: 4000 idx_end: 5000

2_  i:4 idx_start: 6000 idx_end: 7000

2_  i:2 idx_start: 6000 idx_end: 7000

2_  i:6 idx_start: 7000 idx_end: 8000

2_  i:3 idx_start: 7000 idx_end: 8000

2_  i:5 idx_start: 7000 idx_end: 8000

2_  i:1 idx_start: 7000 idx_end: 8000

2_  i:7 idx_start: 7000 idx_end: 8000

Comment: All threads share the same reference.

Comment: Can you explain why it's an issue? Thanks in advance